# Access the fields of a Class object from an ArrayList of those objects

Tags: java, arraylist

The Class MachineParameters has a getReferenceRPM() method,
The ArrayList machineParameterArray has several elements.

I've tried these:

```
System.out.println(machineParameterArray.get(0).getReferenceRPM());

MachineParameters Param1 = machineParameterArray.get(0);
System.out.println(Param1.getReferenceRPM());

System.out.println(MachineParameters.getReferenceRPM(machineParameterArray.get(0)));
```

The println is just for testing, of course I need to access the stored data for processing.
The sample referenceRPM field is a double, others are integers and strings.

Comment: The first two solutions should work, the third one should not. What more do you want to know?

Comment: Can u post the method `getReferenceRPM()`. I've seen two different signatures (`getReferenceRPM()` and `getReferenceRPM(MachineParameters  parameter)`).

Comment: I get null pointer exception errors.

Comment: public double getReferenceRPM() {
     return referenceRPM;
    }

Comment: OK, If I println the ArrayList element I get "null" for all the elements that have been .add-ed. So I guess I'm not .add-ing them in correctly.

Comment: Found the problem - learned a lot.

Comment: Thanks to all and especially Etienne - knowing the get's were correct made me look elsewhere and I located the errors.